# Solving a system of quadratic equations in Python

Tags: python, nonlinear-equations, scipy

I'd like to solve numerically a system of quadratic equations:

$A_{11}x_1+A_{12}x_2+A_{13}x_3+B_{12}x_1x_2+B_{13}x_1x_3=C_1$
$A_{21}x_1+A_{22}x_2+A_{23}x_3+B_{21}x_2x_1+B_{23}x_2x_3=C_2$ 
$A_{31}x_1+A_{32}x_2+A_{33}x_3+B_{31}x_3x_1+B_{32}x_3x_2=C_3$

where $A_{ij}$, $B_{ij}$, $C_i$ are real numbers and $x_i$ the variables (here only three but I have in mind to solve systems up to 50 variables).

I've tried Newton-Krylov method (implemented in scipy) but it does not seem to be stable. I'm now trying to use routines implemented in sympy but I face a problem illustrated by this example:

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.abc import x,y,z
Equations = [x**2 + y + z - 1,
           x + y**2 + z - 1,
           x + y + z**2 - 1]
```

If we use `solve_poly system` we obtain

```
solve_poly_system(Equations, x, y, z)
[(0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0), (1, 0, 0), (-1 + sqrt(2), -1 + sqrt(2), -1 + sqrt(2)), (-sqrt(2) - 1, -sqrt(2) - 1, -sqrt(2) - 1)]
```

and, if we use `solve_triangulated` we obtain

```
solve_triangulated(Equations, x, y, z)
[(0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0), (1, 0, 0)]
```

Some solutions are not found by `solve_triangulated`.
What is the reason? What kind of solutions can we find with  `solve_triangulated`?

Comment: If your are planning to solve for 50 variables, an analytical solution is probably not the way to go. Regarding the differences you see between ``solve_poly_system`` and ``solve_triangulated`` you should ask in a SymPy channel like the gitter chat room or the mailing list.

Comment: Regarding the use of SciPy, I just found the roots using ``fsolve``. You can check the gist here: https://gist.github.com/nicoguaro/3c964ae8d8f11822b6c22768dc9b3716

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've just made some tests with random systems and I'm surprised to see that `fsolve` is much more stable than `newton_krylov` (which often cannot find a solution and raise an error even for small systems). Could be due to the fact that I don't know how to parametrize `newton_krylov`. I will continue with `fsolve`, it can deal apparently with (quadratic) non linear systems with 100 variables in a few minutes.

Comment: After many tests, it seems that `scipy.optimize.root` with `method=lm` and explicit jacobian in input is the best solver for my specific problem (quadratic non linear systems with a few dozens of equations).

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you use regular Newton? Your system is simple enough that you can find its closed-form Jacobian and write your own Newton solver. If you just need one solution which is close to a given starting point (like you wrote on [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/293605/solving-a-system-of-quadratic-equations-with-sympy?noredirect=1#comment728798_293605)), then it rates to work pretty well.

(As I wrote on MO, I guess that there can be up to $2^{\text{number of variables}}$ real solutions, so finding all of them is going to be problematic for $n\approx 50$.)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've implemented it but I face the problem of convergence/divergence of the Newton method. There are some solutions which are indeed found very quickly (the algorithm converges) and there are other solutions which cannot be found even if I give in input an initial starting point which is very close to the solution (because the algorithm diverges). Since `scipy.optimize.root` works well for my problem, I will continue with it (don't think I'll be able to do better with my limited computational skills ...)